# Error on WiX build

Tags: xml, wix, wix3.5

I need to run this windows command on my WIX script:

```
appcmd.exe set config /section:applicationPools /[name='Reviewer'].processModel.identityType:SpecificUser /[name='Reviewer'].processModel.userName:reviewer /[name='Reviewer'].processModel.password:reviewer
```

This command should be placed in a WIX custom action (in place of MYCOMMAND, see below)

```
<CustomAction Id="AssignUserToIISapp" Directory="IISFOLDER" Execute="deferred" Impersonate="no" ExeCommand="MYCOMMAND" Return="check"/>
```

Unfortunately I get a parse error, do I need to escape the single quote or the slashes? I tried escaping the single quotes `\'` but I still get the error:

> error LGHT0204: ICE03: Invalid format string; Table: CustomAction,
>   Column: Target, Key(s): AssignUserToIISapp

Comment: Why don't you use WIX IIS extension http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/iis/website.html

Comment: @ArkadySitnitsky because I made many other similar custom actions and it always worked but I never had to include slashes or single quotes so I'm quite sure I have to escape them somehow

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had to escape the square brackets! `[\[]` and `[\]]` respectively for `[` and `]`